# Bug in my Android App Guessing Game

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

I hope someone can help with this.  I have the below guessing game app for android.

What it's supposed to do is, when the user has guessed wrong three times, it has an alertdialog that says they've guessed incorrectly three times and the answer is....

It does actually do this fine but the bug in question is that if the user gets the answer right on the third attempt, it still brings up the alert that says they got wrong three times as opposed to the alert that tells them they got it right.  Both alerts work fine except for this one time.

Everything else on the app works as I want it to.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

```
public class Task1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

int attempts = 0;
final int maxAttempts = 1;
Random randGen = new Random();
int ranNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

    final TextView textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
    final TextView guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
    final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
    Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);

    randGen = new Random();
    // Generate number once
    ranNum = randGen.nextInt(20);

    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please guess between 0 and 20", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 350);


    // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
    pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Task1Activity.this);
       alert.setTitle("Unlucky");
       alert.setCancelable(false);
       alert.setMessage("You have guessed incorrectly three times. " +
               "The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?")
               //.setCancelable(true)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       //dialog.dismiss();
                       Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
                       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                       startActivity(i);

                   }
               });

                alert
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        //Task1Activity.this.finish();
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       finishAffinity();
                   };
               });

       final AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Task1Activity.this);
       alert2.setTitle("You Did It!");
       alert2.setCancelable(false);
       alert2.setMessage("The answer was " + ranNum + ". " + "Would you like to play again?")
               //.setCancelable(true)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       //dialog.dismiss();
                       Intent i = new Intent(Task1Activity.this, Task1Activity.class);
                       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                       startActivity(i);

                   }
               });

       alert2
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                       //Task1Activity.this.finish();
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       finishAffinity();
                   };
               });



                       int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());

                       if (userNumber > 19) {
                           //guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                           //guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                           toast.show();
                       } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                           guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess again!");
                           guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                       } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                           guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                           guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                       } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                           ranNum = randGen.nextInt(20);
                           //guessText.setText("You did it!");
                           //guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                           alert2.show();
                       }

       if (attempts++ > maxAttempts) {
           alert.show();
           //guessText.setText("You have guessed incorrectly three times.  The answer was " + ranNum);
       } else {
           String randText = "";


                       randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                       textResponse.setText("");

                       userGuess.setText("");


                   }
               }
           }
    );

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside of the if statement on this line;

```
if (attempts++ > maxAttempts)
```

make sure your `maxAttempts` is `2` instead of `1`. Because simply you should try it for `3` times so it should be `0 , 1 and  2`..

So you should make your line

```
final int maxAttempts = 2;
```